# How did the Indian provide the thunder effect?

Tags: feher-klara

In Fehér Klára, *Az indián kertje*, how did the Indian provide a thunder (and possibly lightning) effect at the push of a button?

The revelation explains that the totem pole could speak with a loudspeaker, and also how Zsoli would communicate with the Indian with a two-way radio.  But the thunder effect seems puzzling.  How was it so convincing that multiple children independently believed it to be real thunder?  How could Zsoli activate it in real time?

(Before you close, consider that I'm asking about specifically about the technology-based plot element.
PS. the tag is provisional, please decide how this question should be tagged correctly.)